# Is there any way to read .one files (OneNote Files) in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, microsoft-graph-onenote

I am able to extract files and pages through REST API using

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/
```

But I could find any way where we can read .one files, like we can read .txt,.csv,.xls,.docs files in python.

Is there any library build for this?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=python+onenote https://github.com/DissectMalware/pyOneNote

Comment: I didn't dig into this much, but generally, if there is a VB/CSharp interface to a Microsoft API, you can use python's win32 package to run it. Here is a [OneNote developer reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/onenote/onenote-developer-reference). Sometimes, its better to just crack open Visual Basic instead of jumping through the win32 hoops.